# ASP.Net Set Text Property of ASP Control Element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am learning asp.net web form and run into a bug and couldn't find out what went wrong

I have an aspx with 3 tags with Ids as below

[image]
aspx

If I uncomment the below block, then I will have a null pointer exception when navigate to the page. I am trying to set the text of those 3 Id tags

[image]

This is the exception

[image]

When I set breakpoint, the last executed code is the Page_Load() in Site.Master.cs. It throws the exception as soon as it leaves the method Page_Load()

Could anyone please help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It don't think we can figure it out with that info. Can you find the exact line the error fires on and get an image of the debug error inside VS (not the browser)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your ShoppingCartTitle div contains all of the other controls, so when you set `ShoppingCartTitle.InnerText = "Shopping Cart is Empty"` you are deleting everything within the div, even the controls you are trying to set (labelTotalText and lblTotal, the GridView, everything).  ASP.NET will then try to fill the now non-existent controls when it renders the page.

Instead, try making ShoppingCartTitle it's own div (or prefereable asp:panel), wrap everything else in a separate div and set `Visible` to true or false for each depending on whether the cart is empty or not.  That way the controls still exist as far as ASP.NET is concerned even if they aren't visible, they just don't render to the page.  Don't try to manually clear contents by settings InnerText.